# Dataset of geographic distribution of languages and/or language families across the globe?

Tags: geospatial, language, json, xml

Where can one find a free or open dataset listing the geographic boundaries of languages and/or language *families*, something like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Distribution_of_languages_in_the_world) (but the raw JSON/XML/CSV data behind it):

[image]

Would like to show an interactive map of the major language families across the Earth, ultimately, so need some structured data to work with.

- [Language families list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_language_families) (Wikipedia, without geographic boundaries/coordinates).
- [Random interactive map](https://turanfarsyth.github.io/MyWebApp/index.html) I found.
- Found several other lists of families like [this](https://maps-and-tables.neocities.org/languages_map), but no geographic datasets.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. The data must exist if these maps were to have been created somehow, I'm guessing, but can't seem to find it. [Glottolog's dataset](https://glottolog.org/meta/downloads) is the closest I've found, but it offers central *points* in geocoordinates, not geographic boundaries. For example, English in Glottolog's geocoordinates is listed [here](https://maps.app.goo.gl/gDvmmfZM51Tg96dMA), which is not correct, it should show boundaries covering much of the world.